# Exibir uma mensagem quando a ListView está vazia

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

Tenho um ListAdapter que estende um BaseAdapter que funciona perfeitamente. Quando ele estiver vazio queria que aparecesse uma mensagem qualquer.

Onde implementar essa validação?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A implementação é muito simples.

Você só precisa de declarar um `TextView` com `android:id="@android:id/empty"` no layout onde declarou a `ListView` que vai ser gerida pelo `Adapter`.

**Layout:**

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="No data"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Se a `Activity` que tem esse layout for derivada(extends) de `ListActivity` o Android fará o resto por você.

Caso seja derivada de `Activity/AppCompatActivity`, terá de dizer à `ListView` qual o `TextView` que tem essa função.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
TextView emptyView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
list.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Neste caso é possível usar qualquer tipo de View e pode atribuir-lhe outro id que não `@android:id/empty`.

Comment: Muito Bom! Obrigado!