# Como mudar o Layout exibido dinamicamente

Tags: android, android-layout

Quero fazer isso, atualmente tenho uma ListView que é incorporada dentro do meu activity_main.xml
da seguinte forma:

```
<include layout="@layout/lista_categoria" />
```

Gostaria de saber uma forma para exibir outro layout (em tempo de execução) dentro desse include se o ListView estiver vazio

por exemplo mostrando o layout layout_404.xml caso não tenha nada para exibir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível mudar o conteúdo de um `<include>`, mas é possível fazê-lo num [ViewGroup.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), pois pode-se adicionar e remover *views* dele.

No local onde quer substituir uma *view* por outra coloque um *FrameLayout* e atribua-lhe um *ID*.

Crie um *xml* para cada uma dessas *views*.

Crie um objecto para cada uma delas:

```
view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view1, null);
view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view2, null);
```

Obtenha a referência ao *FrameLayout*:

```
frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
```

Adicione a primeira *view* ao *FrameLayout*:

```
frameLayout.addView(layout1);
```

Quando quiser mudar de *view*, remova as *views* do *FrameLayout* e adicione a nova:

```
frameLayout.removeAllViews();
frameLayout.addView(layout2);
```

Caso apenas queira colocar um texto quando a lista estiver vazia, veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/2541).

Comment: Eu ja fiz com include. Não fica tão elegante quanto essa alternativa que tu postou, mas funciona.

Comment: @TiagoPCasemiro Eu vi a sua resposta, mas ela não muda de layout, apenas muda a visibilidade. No entanto, é uma opção/solução válida.

Answer (score 0):

Tem que definir IDs para os layouts, tipo  ex:

```
<LinearLayout ...
android:id="@+id/Layout1">
```

Na activity que vc quiser, instancia um layout, e atribui ele pelo ID:

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findById(R.id.Layout1);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
layout1.addView(1, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_layout, this, false) );
```

Obs, atenção para o tipo de layout, (linear, Relative.. etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
<include id="@+id/layout_1" layout="@layout/lista_categoria" android:visibility="visible" />
<include id="@+id/layout_2" layout="@layout/layout_404" android:visibility="gone" />

View layout1 = findViewById(R.id.lista_categoria);
View layout1 = findViewById(R.id.layout_404);

// Para fazer a troca
layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Para desfazer a troca
layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Não é elegante mais funciona. O listView ja possui  uma implemenação para layout vazio. Olhe esse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565451/display-no-item-message-in-listview

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma seria essa.

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"  //Esse layout aqui seria seu layout 404 customizado
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```