# Método setEmptyView não está funcionando no meu listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Estou setando o método setEmptyView na minha listview porém quando ela fica vazia ela não mostra a view desejada, e também não dá nenhum erro no log.

```
public class ListaNotificacoes extends Fragment{

View minha_view;

private ListView lista_notify;
private ImageView botao_deletar;
private ItensDoAdaptador itens_adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    minha_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_notificacoes, container, false);
    return minha_view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    recupera_tarefa();

    }

    public void recupera_tarefa(){

        try {
            Cursor cursor = banco_dados.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lista_notificacoes order by id DESC", null);

            //recupera os ids da coluna
            int indiceColunaId = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
            int indiceColunaTexto = cursor.getColumnIndex("texto_notificacao");
            int indiceColunaHora = cursor.getColumnIndex("hora_notificacao");

            final ArrayList<ItensDaLista> lista_menu = new ArrayList<>();

            itens_adapter = new ItensDoAdaptador(getActivity(), lista_menu);
            lista_notify = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_notify);
            lista_notify.setAdapter(itens_adapter);

            lista_notify.setEmptyView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_listview, null));

            //listar as notificações
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor != null) {
                String teste = cursor.getString(indiceColunaId);
                lista_menu.add(new ItensDaLista(teste.toString(),cursor.getString(indiceColunaTexto),cursor.getString(indiceColunaHora),R.drawable.delete));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que a ListView possa controlar a View a apresentar quando está vazia é necessário que ela esteja no mesmo nível na hierarquia dela.

Da forma como você está a fazer isso não acontece.

Faça assim:

```
//inflate da empty_listview
View emptyView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_listview, null);
//Adiciona-a na mesma hierarquia da ListView
((ViewGroup) lista_notify.getParent()).addView(emptyView);
//Informa a ListView que deve usá-la como empty view
lista_notify.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

No entanto, o mais simples é essa *view* ser declarada no *xml* no mesmo nível da ListView, e obtê-la com `findViewById()`

Comment: Mas se ela estiver no xml da listview ele vai ficar aparecendo já mesmo sem estar vazia

Comment: Não, não aparece. Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/2541).

Comment: Se eu entendi bem o seu código, você está a fazer algo "esquisito" que é o fragment estar a preencher uma ListView existente na activity. Isso deve ser feito na activity e não no fragment. Ou então passe a ListView para o fragment.

Comment: já consegui fazer funcionar o setEmptyView só que ele não quer remover a view quando já tem itens na lista, você sabe por que ?